# Google Search API returns only 1% of total impressions of site

Tags: google-search-console

So, I'm working on SEO for a site that gets about 5 million impressions a month. However, queries to the GSC API gives me a very small subset of the overall impressions, usually on the order of 1-2%. My request string is (code in python):

```
        request = {
          'startDate': date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), #Date
          'endDate': date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
          'dimensions': ['page'],
          'rowLimit': 5000,
          'startRow': row_count, #Starts at 0. Then counts the number of 
rows in the response. If the response has more than 0 rows, the API is invoked again, with row_count equal to the number of rows in the previous response. 
          'aggregationType' :"byPage"
      }
```

Using this gets me data for about 1-2% of the overall impression received by the site, according to GSC.

When I add a dimension 'query' to this request, the data becomes significantly smaller, usually on the order of .5% or less of the overall impressions!

Additionally, even though the rowLimit is set to 5k, each response with dimension page & query, gives me just a few hundred rows of data, requiring me to loop and send a large number of requests for a single page. Just to illustrate what I mean: 175 calls were made for 2018-07-01. The first request resulted in 446 rows; the 8th in about 400; and the 2nd to last in just 5.

```
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  1  row  0
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  2  row  446
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  3  row  850
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  4  row  1234
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  5  row  1612
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  6  row  1986
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  7  row  2361
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  8  row  2736
...
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  173  row  47725
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  174  row  47730
2018-07-01 00:00:00 Loop  175  row  47735
```

Finally, the data I get with dimension & query is not only about .5% of the total impressions, but it is also full of duplicates! Of the 47735 rows I get for this day, once duplicates are removed, only about 3k remain!

Am I doing something horribly wrong, or is this API totally broken?

My entire code (excluding the part I use to connect to the API):

```
import pandas as pd
import time
col_names = ['keys', 'clicks', 'impressions','ctr','position']
newDF = pd.DataFrame()


for date in date_generated:
    #print(date)
    i = 1
    row_count = 0
    row_remaining = True
    newDF_temp = pd.DataFrame()
    while row_remaining == True: 
        request = {
              'startDate': date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
              'endDate': date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
              'dimensions': ['page','query'],
              'rowLimit': 5000,
              'startRow': row_count,
              'aggregationType' :"byPage"
          }
        #time.sleep(5)
        response = execute_request(webmasters_service, 'https://...', request)
        if 'rows' not in response:
            row_remaining = False
            print("breaking",date)
            break
        if 'rows' in response:
            print(date, "Loop ",i, " row ", row_count)
            i = i+1
        keys,clicks,imp,ctr,pos,dt = [],[],[],[],[],[]
        for result in response['rows']:
            keys.append(result['keys'])
            clicks.append(result['clicks'])
            imp.append(result['impressions'])
            ctr.append(result['ctr'])
            pos.append(result['position'])
            dt.append(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        df = pd.DataFrame([keys,clicks,imp,ctr,pos,dt]).T
        row_count = len(df) + row_count
        newDF_temp=newDF_temp.append(df)
    newDF_temp = newDF_temp.iloc[newDF_temp.astype(str).drop_duplicates().index]
    newDF=newDF.append(newDF_temp)
```